# How long does variable exist in temporary storage?

Tags: c++, copy, temporary-objects, return-by-reference

Currently I am learning  C++ with 6th edition C++ Primer Plus by Steven Prata and on p. 389 I found smth very interesting that I would like to clarify for myself.
If we have some function like this:

```
const std::string     &ft_add_on_sides(std::string s1, std::string s2)
{
        std::string          res;
        res = s2 + s1 + s2;
        return (s2);
}

int     main(void)
{
        std::string input = "Hello"
        std::string result = ft_add_on_sides(input, "###");
        return (0);
}
```

As far as I understand, this function is expecting two string objects which will be **copies** of those, which programmer will actually pass. And this function will return const reference to some memory address.
But I am interested in return statement:
As *s1* or *s2* are located in a **temporary storage**, we can gain access to them, but when will they be destroyed? Won't I get into troubles with such return statement?
Add. Cause the variable can be destroyed and I am still asking for its address.

Comment: Deleted my previous answer because, after I wrote that this does not return by reference, I saw the `&`. The unusual coding style confused me; pardon. I should have paid closer attention. But? You might consider tweaking your style. If you want a full tab between the type and the function name, to more clearly separate them, then logically you would want the return type to be `std::string&` or `char*`, and not group `&` or `*` with the function name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters of a function are destroyed as soon as the `return` statement has executed, before the calling function continues. That means you can still use these parameters inside the `return` value expression, but you'd better return a *copy* of them.

What you wrote in your example is Undefined Behavior. Anything can happen. Typically, in debug modes compilers are reasonably good in catching accesses to destroyed strings, but in release builds the compiler no longer introduces code to catch bugs.

Comment: @Davislor Its returned as a reference, the `&` is just glue to the function's name. Without eliding, when you call the function, you have two constructors of `std::string` called, first with `const char *`, that constructs a temporary that will be destroyed at the end of the expression, and another move-constructor that constructs `s2`. `s2` should be destroyed at the end of the function according to the standard, but this not what happens in most implementation (`s2` is destroyed at the end of the expression).

Answer (score -1):

You can read the accepted answer here.

[Return value of function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100462/return-value-of-function)

`the return value is copied out of a local variable into the return register if necessary.`

The functions' stack frame is no longer needed, the local variables are popped off and will not be accessible once the function returns, but `s2` will be copied into the return register.

Comment: Yeah, I got it, but I wonder whether s2 is a **local variable**? I mean, aren't there any two separated storages, one: function stack, where all variables declared inside the function are located and temporary storage where all temporary objects are settled? Look, my function is expecting std::string but gets const char* as second parameter.

Comment: You are linking a C answer, while this question is directly linked to the concept of (const) reference, which does not exist in C...

Comment: @rbozhko 1) "_I wonder whether s2 is a local variable?_" Yes. 2) "_my function is expecting std::string but gets const char* as second parameter._" Your function receives a `std::string`. The constructor of `std::string`, which expects `char*` (the same one, which allows you to do `std::string input = "Hello";`) gets invoked implicitly.